# How to remove pairs of identical digits from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked this question in Python interview and wasn't able to solve it.

Starting from left side of a string that consists only of digits, adjacent digits pair up in battle and the larger digit wins.
If two digits are same, they both lose. A lone digit automatically wins.

Write a program that takes a string of digits and return the victorious digits. If all numbers lose return 'total carnage'

Example:

```
Sample Input 1: 578921445
Sample Output 1: 7925

Sample Input 2: 778899
Sample Output 2: Total Carnage
```

I have tried this to check the repeated digits. Now, how do I remove repeated digits and only print the other unrepeated digits?

```py
def hasSameDigits(x):
    digits = set()
    output = ""
    for d in str(x):
        if d in digits:
            return True
        digits.add(d)
    return False


print(hasSameDigits(12345))
```

Comment: Create a new string with the "winners".

Answer (score 0):

Without using modules like regex (which make it easier) here is the code you want:

```
def battle(num):
    final_ans = ''
    for i in range(0, len(num), 2):
        try:
            if int(num[i]) > int(num[i+1]):
                final_ans += num[i]
            elif int(num[i]) < int(num[i+1]):
                final_ans += num[i+1]
        except IndexError:
            final_ans += num[i]

    if len(final_ans) == 0:
        final_ans = 'Total Carnage'

    return final_ans


print(battle('123456789'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the specific part of the problem that you mentioned, to remove the repeated digits, you can do it with sets as you have started. For example:

```
def has_same_digits(x):
    return "".join(x[y:y+2] for y in range(0, len(x), 2) if len(set(x[y:y+2])) == 2)
```

This creates a list of pairs of digits where the set of those digits has a length of 2 (i.e. not the same), and joins them back into a string, but you could achieve the exact same thing without sets with:

```
def has_same_digits(x):
    "".join(x[y:y+2] for y in range(0, len(x), 2) if x[y] != x[y+1])
```

To complete the problem, you need to add in the battle, and when you do that, you don't actually need to specifically check if they are the same or not, as you already need to work out who won so can just return nothing if neither digit won.

```
def has_same_digits(x):
    result = "".join(x[y] if x[y] > x[y+1] else x[y+1] if x[y] < x[y+1] else '' for y in range(0, len(x), 2))
    return result if result else "Total Carnage"
```

This parses the string, comparing pairs of numbers and returns either the first, the second or neither, based on your criteria, to be joined to form the result string.

The only remaining problem is to handle lone digits.

```
def has_same_digits(x):
    length = len(x) if len(x)%2 == 0 else len(x) - 1
    result = "".join(x[y] if x[y] > x[y+1] else x[y+1] if x[y] < x[y+1] else '' for y in range(0, length, 2))
    if length < len(x):
        result += x[-1]
    return result if result else "Total Carnage"
```

This simply causes the parsing to ignore the last digit, if there's an odd number of digits, and then simply adds it back on to the string before returning the result (or "Total carnage" if the result is an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

You want tiny simplified and straightforward code solution?

```
def battle(digits):
    if len(digits) <= 1:
        return digits
    elif digits[0] == digits[1]:
        return ''
    else:
        return str(max(int(digits[0]), int(digits[1])))
    
def war(digits):
    winners = ''
    for i in range(0, len(digits), 2):
        winners += battle(digits[i:i+2])
    if winners == '':
        return "Total carnage"
    else:
        return winners
```